# ASP.NET - getting a form's fields to line up with CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

I'm trying to learn how to line up fields of a form using CSS instead of tables.  I'm having a hard time with a CheckBox control.  Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

```
<label for="CheckBox1">CheckBox</label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<br />
<label for="TextBox1">TextBox</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div>

</div>
</form>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body
{
}

label
{
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

I'm getting something that looks like this:

CheckBox    []

[CheckBox1]    TextBox    [     ]

Why is [CheckBox1] on the next line?

Here's a pic:
[image]

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is going to be controversial, but I use a **TABLE** for stuff like this. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked on ASP.Net but if I remember correctly, the checkbox control has a property that lets you specify where the text appears (below it or to the side). That may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[CheckBox1] only appears in design view - if you run the application you will see that it is not there.

[CheckBox1] appears in design view because you have not set the text for the checkbox - it looks like you are using a label instead.